# Return a struct from a function containg a static array in C

Tags: c

```
struct MyStruct
{
  int i; 
  double arr[10];

};


struct MyStruct func()
{


};
```

When returned from the function, will be fully copied to a local variable?

```
struct Mystruct ms = func();
```

Comment: There is an extra semicolon in the first block at the end of the func() definition.

Answer (score 5):

Yes you can, the structure will be fully copied.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if `func()` returns a variable of type `Mystruct`.

Comment: @vz0: I know, but there aren't any returns in his example code.

Comment: Oh, right, I misunderstood your answer, the return statement is missing.

Answer (score 0):

The *correct* way to do this:

```
void func(struct MyStruct* by_ref);

int main()
    {
      struct MyStruct ms;
      func(&ms);
    }
```

This won't upload a bombastic struct on the stack, nor will you get issues with static variables. Returning a pointer to a static variable is very bad for the following reasons:

1. It breaks private encaptulation. Very bad program design.
2. A multi-threaded program doing this gets vulnerable.
3. Pure bugs, as in this example:

> ```
> static uint8 static_str[6];
>
> uint8* func(const uint8 str[6])
> {
>   uint8 i;
>
>   for(i=0; i<6; i++)
>   {
>     static_str[i] = str[i];
>   }
>
>   return static_str;
> }
>
> int main()
> {
>   print_strings(func(“hello”), func(“world”));
> }
> ```

The output from a function printing the two strings will be either “hello hello” or “world world” (depending on the order of evaluation of function parameters).

Answer (score -1):

You have no return value so in any case you need to set that. Furthermore, it is better to use a pointer:

```
struct MyStruct* func()
{
     struct MyStruct *pMyStruct=calloc(1,sizeof(struct MyStruct));

     /* fill struct */


     return pMyStruct; 
};
```

Comment: This isn't always better. If it's not performance-critical, I'd go with returning by value since it's less memory-leak-prone. Or, alternatively, I'd declare func() as `void func(struct MyStruct* myStruct)` and fill the struct passed by pointer. Each approach has it's own pros and cons, there is no best one.

Comment: True, as long as you provide a return statement (as BlackBear pointed out). My idea was that you might want to return a pointer instead of the complete structure.

Comment: No that isn't good at all, if the struct is static. You will get all kind of issues, particularly if the code is called like this: print(func(), func()). That code will never work if you return a pointer to a static.

Comment: @Sergey: I agree that if performance is no issue passing by value is more clear. @Lundin: the structure is not static.

Comment: @Martin I assue it is to be treated as one, after reading the subject of the question. Regardless, returning a pointer is still bad practice.